# Is there any replacement for actingas() function in laravel 5.0?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5

In laravel 5.1 and up, we can use actingas() function.
There is no actingas function in the Laravel 5.0 documentation.
Are there any replacement or solution for it?

Comment: It is available, Search "actingas" in this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing

Comment: Don't abuse the code blocks

Comment: @Redo: It was my edit, I used them for highlighting code keywords like the function's name and for the framework's version, I don't really consider it as "abuse code blocks". In comments there's a link to the 5.1 documentation, so the edit would have been surely helpful for the question's comprension, from my point of view.

Comment: @ExDev In general, _abusing code block_ means using the code block in places in which it not supposed to be used. The name, the version, etc should not be highlighted using code blocks. We're rejecting lots and lots of such edits every day. Please use _italic_ or **bold** to highlight important words. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Laravel 5.0 equivalent of `actingAs()` is `be()` :

```
$this->be($user);
```

The documentation reference [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/testing#helper-methods). Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 4):

`actingAs` is actually an alias of `be` method.

If you look inside `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\ApplicationTrait` then you can see that it is referring back to `be`.

```php
/**
 * Set the currently logged in user for the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable  $user
 * @param  string|null  $driver
 * @return $this
 */
public function actingAs(UserContract $user, $driver = null)
{
    $this->be($user, $driver);

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Anyway . . . :-)